# How to redirect away from Facebook's homepage?

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, facebook

When I check Facebook, automatically I land on the News Feed which has a lot of information I would rather never have to see. Thus, I want to redirect the homepage to my profile page. I have installed the Google Chrome extension Switcheroo, and added a rule to redirect https://www.facebook.com to my profile URL, but this breaks all the things because now whenever I access any facebook.com url, I am redirected to my homepage.

If I could play with regular expressions I could create the correct redirect but at the moment it doesn't seem that Switcheroo allows that. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Use a bookmark on the bookmarks bar. Its what I use to provide similar functionality w/ youtube.

Comment: Thanks for that tip and I'll definitely use that in the meantime, but I would like to get it set up with the redirect though in the long term.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) and keep in mind to use "Url Equals" when you are making a new rule.That's the point which won't redirect ***any url containing*** https://www.facebook.com, but will redirect only exact https://www.facebook.com.

[image]